# ElastAlert and changing E-mail content

Tags: elastalert

I've just gotten started with ElastAlert and I love it. I have an application up and running that basically sends me e-mails. My problem now is that the e-mails contain a whole bunch of unnecessary information that I would like to remove.

I've looked around but haven't found any way of doing this. Is there a simple way how I can change the content of my e-mail to make it a bit simpler? Such as specifying exactly which fields I want to see.

Best regards! And thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Example rule config part for custom email content.

```
alert:
- "email"
alert_text_type: alert_text_only
alert_text: "
Disk Used : {0:.2%}\n
Mount Point : {1}\n
Host : {2}\n
Timestamp : {3}"
alert_text_args: ["system.filesystem.used.pct","system.filesystem.mount_point","beat.hostname","@timestamp"]
email:
- "devops@example.com"
```

Email Content Sample:

```
 Disk Used : 85.00%
 Mount Point : /
 Host : example_hostname
 Timestamp : 2019-01-14T06:04:46.221Z
```

[Reference](https://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ruletypes.html#alert-content)